# now that appengine datastore queries are no longer capped to 1000 are there performance issues if one were to use an offset of say 250000

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Say I have a million records in a model in the appengine datstore. Will I pay a performance penalty with the following query.

```
records = MyModel.all().filter("words =", "foo").fetch(offset=250000, limit=20)
```

From the [appengine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html) it says

```
The query has performance characteristics that correspond linearly
with the offset amount plus the limit.
```

Or Would I have to create an index and do something like

```
records = MyModel.all().filter("words =", "foo").filter("pub_date >", last_date).fetch(20)
```

I'm trying to see if I can query against a StringListProperty without adding any indexes to the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the index will almost certainly give you better performance, particularly as the number of entities increase.

If you specify an offset the datastore will scan over `offset` entities before your application will start getting results.  The two [bullet points](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html#GqlQuery_fetch) above the one you quote explain a bit more:

> The first offset results are not
>   skipped by the datastore itself.

Comment: Would you know if that means that the datstore does an 'n' number of reads where n=offset or does it do one extra read and 'jumps' to the offset

Comment: `offset` does not cause the datastore to jump `n` records; it will have to scan (read) over the `n` records.  Indexes will let the datastore 'jump' to the proper position to start scanning.

Comment: @molicule - In fact, it would be just like you used `.fetch(offset=0, limit 250020)` and then skipped the first 250k records yourself. I would really avoid it :)